# React color background on event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, themes, react-props

I use the npm package **use-dark-mode** as the name implies, it makes it possible to change the theme to light or dark, The problem is that I want to change the background-color of some blocks when changing the theme to dark, and vice versa, return the old color when I switch to light mode, for example, my block background is orange, I switch to dark mode, it turns red and when I switch to light mode, it returns old orange

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css'
import Content from "./components/Content/Content";
import Dark_Mode from "./components/Dark Mode/Dark_Mode";

const App = () => {
  return(
      <div>
          <Dark_Mode />
          <Content />
      </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Content.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css'

const Content = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className={"content_container"}>
                <h3>Hello from React.JS</h3>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Content;
```

**Dark_Mode.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import useDarkMode from 'use-dark-mode';

const DarkModeToggle = () => {
    const darkMode = useDarkMode(false);

    return (
        <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={darkMode.disable}>
                ☀
            </button>
            <button type="button" onClick={darkMode.enable}>
                ☾
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default DarkModeToggle;
```

**style.css**

```
@import '../../App.css';

.content_container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: orange;
}

.content_container h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**App.css**

```
body.light-mode {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}
body.dark-mode {
  background-color: #1a1919;
  color: #999;
}

:root {
  --color-orange: orange;
}
```

As you can see, I have **App.css** when the theme changes, it changes the background of the `<body>`, I still have **Content.jsx** when switching theme I want to change the background of the block with the `className` **content_container** which is connected to **style.css**, In addition, you may have noticed that I tried to use global styles, but I failed. Finally, I would like to show a screenshot on the site for a clear understanding of everything.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give the root element a class on theme change and use css variables in root, but be class specific:

Dark_mode.jsx:

```
function setTheme(themeName) {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove('light-theme', 'dark-theme');
    
    document.documentElement.classList.add(themeName);
}

const DarkModeToggle = () => {
    const activateDarkTheme = () => setTheme('dark-theme');
    const activateLightTheme = () => setTheme('light-theme');

    return (
        <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={activateDarkTheme}>
                ☀
            </button>
            <button type="button" onClick={activateLightTheme}>
                ☾
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Styles:

```
:root, // this is used for the default theme, will be overwritten by other styles with classes because of specifity
:root.dark-theme {
    --color-bg: #000;
}

:root.light-theme {
    --color-bg: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand very well where I need to apply the function switchTheme?

Comment: on the button click...I'll edit the code to clarify

Comment: I tried to apply your variant, but I did not succeed, I will give you a link to the project on codesandbox, can you see? https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-leftpad-rjhpb

Comment: I see...you'll have to use the variables. So for every color / style that you want to change by changing the theme you'll have to create a variable and in the component's styles say: `someStyleProperty: var(--theNameOfTheVariableSetInRoot)`

Comment: So for my example you'd have to put this in the body styles: `background-color: var(--color-bg)`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-sanne-4i2od   I implemented some examples in the app.css stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

I found a more convenient solution! although it is my fault, I was a little inattentive and did not study the documentation of this package that I use in my project, here is a simple solution

**Content.jsx**

```
import './Content.css'
import useDarkMode from 'use-dark-mode';

export default function Content () {

    const { value } = useDarkMode(false);

    return <div>
        <div className={value ? 'Dark_Mode' : 'Light_Mode'}>
            <h3>Hello from React.JS</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Content.css**

```
.Dark_Mode {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 275px;
    background-color: orange;
  }
  
  .Light_Mode {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 275px;
    background-color: rgb(24, 106, 199);
  }
```